# How to call functions in postgres without SELECT?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I created the following function for my `postgresql`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(param INT) RETURNS VOID AS..
```

How can I call that function without `SELECT`?
When I run `SELECT myfunc(1)` it will work, even though it does not return anything by design.

But I want to run it without the select, just `myfunc(1)`, which does not work and tells me `Syntax error at 1`.

I'm trying to implement the db_merge function from [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/1109198#1109198).

I cannot run `SELECT db_merge(..)` from java as this will give me a `"A result was returned when none was expected."), PSQLState.TOO_MANY_RESULTS)`error.

Comment: "*I cannot run SELECT db_merge(..) from java*" - that's not true. `Statement.execute("select db_merge()")` will work just fine. You just can't use `executeUpdate()` because that's not allowed to return something.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I running it within a `executeBatch()` from statement, which is called by `JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()`. So I could probably not use that?

Comment: `JdbcTemplate.execute(String)` is designed for DDL statements. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-java.lang.String- -- use one of the others `execute(String, ResultSetExtractor|RowCallbackHandler|RowMapper)` & simply discard the results.

Comment: You didn't mention that you were using Spring. My comment relates to plain JDBC.

Comment: In JDBC you can use the `{call myfunc()}` escape, but it just does a `SELECT` behind the scenes anyway. I fail to see what the problem with this is.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that (you cannot call a stored function without issuing a `SELECT` statement in PostgreSQL). Also, PostgreSQL [does not support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html) the `CALL` statement.

More about [calling functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) in PostgreSQL.

Note: within PL/pgSQL context, you have to use [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) (instead of `SELECT`) if your called function has `RETURNS void`.

**Edit**:

In case of JDBC, do not use`executeUpdate()`, just use `execute()` like with any other SELECT statement.

In case of Spring's JdbcTemplate: [`execute(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-java.lang.String-) is designed for DDL statements; use one of the others & simply discard the results:

- `query(String, ResultSetExtractor)`
- `query(String, RowCallbackHandler)`
- `query(String, RowMapper)`

Comment: My PL is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/1109198#1109198, and does only have `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. How could I else execute the function in postgresql without the select, as the function should return void? What are my chances?

Comment: @membersound That doesn't matter, `SELECT` will always return data (in case of `RETURNS void` functions, it will return a single `NULL`).

Comment: @membersound in case of JDBC, do not use `executeUpdate()`, just use `execute()` like with any other `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres messaging protocol allows for [direct function invocation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/protocol-flow.html#AEN99133), and the Postgres JDBC driver exposes this through the [Fastpath class](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/fastpath/Fastpath.html). The [driver documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/ext.html) explains how to set it up.